# Is it possible to create a multiple-choice question from Youtube video using Chatgpt?

Tags: chatgpt

Is it possible to create a multiple-choice question about a Youtube video using Chatgpt (or others)?

Comment: I must be missing something?  This looks far too simple to be a Stack Exchange question.  // AFAIK, ChatGPT can't watch videos, but I can't think of any reason why you couldn't coerce it into making a multiple-choice question about anything.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Not multiple choice, but maybe the Wisdolia plugin for Chrome is helpful: https://www.wisdolia.com/